# How to change Tomcat password?

Tags: tomcat

Although I change the password in the Tomcat tomcat-users.xml file I can't access tomcat manager. please tell me what could be the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to give your user a certain role. For version 7 it needs to be "manager-script" (look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/manager-howto.html)). For version 6 "manager-gui" (look [here](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/manager-howto.html))

Answer (score 3):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<tomcat-users> <role rolename="tomcat"/> 
  <role rolename="role1"/> 
  <role rolename="admin"/> 
  <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="tomcat"/> 
  <user username="tomcat" password="" roles="tomcat,role1"/> 
  <user username="role1" password="tomcat" roles="role1"/>
  <user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin"/>
  <user  password="password"  roles="manager-script,admin" username="tomcat"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

user is tomcat 
password is password

this line xml comments sometime your command changing a comment using good for programmer notepad is good one  or other highlighters  not using a word or notepad

Answer (score 0):

create   role rolename="manager"/

role rolename="admin"/

user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manger"/

Saved it and restart Tomcat, now you can access Tomcat admin or manger pages with user =

"admin" and password = "admin".

check this link

http://www.mkyong.com/tomcat/tomcat-default-administrator-password/

Answer (score 0):

Restart the server after changing username and password in tomcat-user.xml file

Answer (score 0):

We can change the username and password for tomcat

Open the `tomcat-user.xml` file in tomcat folder.

we need to alter conf/tomcat-users.xml by adding new user with the role "manager-gui" as shown below

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui"/>
```

[image]

In the similar way

we can alter/provide any roles.

```
<role rolename="manager-gui"/>
<role rolename="manager-script"/>
<role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
<role rolename="manager-status"/>
<role rolename="admin"/>
<user username="admin" password="admin" roles="admin,manager-gui,manager-script"/>
```